# 16MHz ceramic resonator 3pin vs 2 pin

Tags: ceramic, resonator

i want to make this project:

https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Bare-Minimum-Arduino-Mega-2560/

but i found one of the parts is 16MHz ceramic resonator with **3pin**.

i want to know :

1- what is the difference between 2 and 3 pin 16MHz ceramic resonator ?

2- can i use 2pin instead 3pin without problem ?

Comment: Please post the part number for the resonator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three-pin ceramic resonator includes internal capacitors. These capacitors help resonate the piezo-ceramic element at 16 MHz. in a Pierce-type oscillator.
 The 2-pin ceramic resonator omits these capacitors - **you have to add them yourself** For a 16 MHz 2-pin ceramic resonator, these might be in the 30pF ballpark. However, the 2-pin ceramic resonator is more versatile - it can be used in oscillator circuits other than the ubiquitous Pierce oscillator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCBSVR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And you cannot just drop a two-pin resonator into a board designed for a three-pin: you need to add appropriately-valued capacitors.

Comment: @glen_geek thanks for you great answer . i read datasheet of atmega1280 its suggest 12-22pF capacitor . why you suggest 30pF?

Comment: One of the ceramic resonator manufacturers recommended about 30pf for frequencies above 10MHz. 12-22pf sounds like capacitors meant for a **crystal** resonator (not ceramic). Recognize that these capacitors are required for oscillation in the first place (as @TimWescott has mentioned). Their specific value also affects frequency somewhat as well. Frequency of ceramic is not as stable as frequency of crystal.

Comment: The capacitor values for a crystal or other resonator oscillator depend on the resonator, as @glen_geek mentions.  They also depend on the parasitic capacitance at the microprocessor pins, and any capacitance in the board (which is not trivial, because the capacitances involved are so small).

Usually the only bad thing that happens if you're off by a little bit in the chosen capacitance is that the oscillator frequency is off.  Sometimes, however, you may find that the oscillator won't start under certain circumstances (i.e., over your desired operating temperature range).

Comment: If you type "choosing capacitor values for crystal oscillators" into your search engine you'll get lots of useful hits.  For resonators, just think of them as a cheap (in both senses of the word) crystal.